# Hair renders different than the preview

Tags: particles, hair

I made the eyelashes for my mesh and though it will be fine as it looks in the picture
[image]

[image]

Particle Edit
Object mode
but after I render the eyelashes look very messy
like this
[image]
What I am doing wrong?
Here my Hair settings
[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subdivision surface setting on the mesh was different and view/render. the problem got solved by changing this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Look for normal editing (blendforweb or inner blender normal edit modifiers)for your curves/meshes or try edit normals at Paricle/advanced hair/Velocity shelf

Comment: Sorry, do you have a link about?. I don't undertand where specifically is this whay you say. Do you mean the issue is in my mesh not in the particle settings?

Comment: Is this an add-on?