# hair renders weirdly

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

there is a discrepancy between the viewport hair ( how I intend it to be) and the render in Cycles

What's the reason for this difference

[image: viewport]

[image: render]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it can also be a result of using a mirror modifyer. you can easily fix it by applying it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hair renders different than the preview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88302/hair-renders-different-than-the-preview)

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with "use modifier stack" checkbox in particles setting and hair grooming. Subsurf level should be the same for viewport and for render.[image]